# convert string to an array and give array result titles in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am converting string to an array but i need to add titles to results i'm getting . please help:

```
// Get all coordinates from interface and pass it to an array
var latidudes_from_db = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".a"), input => input.value);
var longitudes_from_db = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".b"), input => input.value);

strings = latidudes_from_db.map((lat, i) => [lat, 
                                             longitudes_from_db[i]].join());
var markers = JSON.parse("[" + strings + "]");
console.log(markers);
```

output i get :

```
       0:-1.951
       1:30.095
       2:-1.942
       3:30.095
```

output i desire to have:

```
[ 
  {
    "latitude": '0:-1.951',
    "longitude": '1:30.095'
  },
  {
    "latitude":  '2:-1.942',
    "longitude": '3:30.095'
  }
]
```

Comment: the markers variable is an object or an array?

Comment: Can you post how `latidudes_from_db` looks like?

Comment: @ArigiWiratama markers are arrays

Comment: @Psidom i edited my code check how it looks like

Comment: @gramandagrandish Look my answer below, I hope that can help you :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get all coordinates from interface and pass it to an array
   var latidudes_from_db = [ '1' , '2' ]
 var longitudes_from_db = ['3','4']

var markers = latidudes_from_db.map((lat, i) => {
  return {
   latitude: lat,
   longitude: longitudes_from_db[i]
   };
});
console.log(markers);
```

Instead of returning `[lat, longitudes_from_db[i]].join()` within a `map` function you can return

```
{
"latitude" : lat,
"longitude" : longitudes_from_db[i]
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a code snippet. It doesn't gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm if you want to make it from an array I think we can use `map()` function and use condition on it.

Here's I make sample code for you.

```js
var markers = [
 "0:-1.951",
  "1:30.095",
  "2:-1.942",
  "3:30.095"
];

var newArr = [];
var obj = {};

markers.map(function(marker, index){
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    obj.latitude = marker
  } else {
    obj.longitude = marker
  }
  
  if (Object.keys(obj).length == 2) {
    newArr.push(obj);
    obj = {}
  }
})
console.log(newArr)
```

Okay I hope it can fix your problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You could just construct the object while mapping over `latitudes_from_db`:

```js
var latitudes_from_db = [-1.951, -1.942];
var longitudes_from_db = [30.095, 30.095];

console.log(
    latitudes_from_db.map((lat, i) => ({
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: longitudes_from_db[i]
    }))
);
```